# Adding balls, paddles...etc to Pong

Tags: iphone, objective-c

There are things like UIImageView, UIImage and etc. If I want to import images like a paddle(used by user) or a ball that acts like an object and not just some sprite that ghosts through everything... What should I use? Are there any tutorials about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of information about game development.
All you need is just to apply your math knowledge (school math) in programming.
I found tutorial for you about Pong:
http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/01/15/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: I used this tutorial. I downloaded the whole program at the end and ran it with my iOS simulator. The ball moves around and bounces on the edges of the screen, but the paddles do not move and the collisions aren't... well occuring.

Comment: Fixed it, thank you for this. The program serves as an perfect reference. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you would probably want to create your own custom object for each type. Then the objects would all have a reference to separate `UIImageViews` that display their image. Then of course you would need logic to detect collisions, just like in any other language.

- [Collision Detection](http://makemacgames.com/2005/10/24/collision-detection-with-cocoa/)